# How many total perks are there in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How many total perks are in *Elder Scrolls: Skyrim* and does it vary for different skills?

Comment: + 1 for a good question, but also for your username :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a total of 251 perks.

#### Path of Might – 91

- Smithing: 10
- Heavy Armor: 12
- Block: 13
- Two-handed: 19
- One-handed: 21
- Archery: 16

#### Path of Shadow – 74

- Light Armor: 10
- Sneak: 13
- Lockpicking: 11
- Pickpocket: 12
- Speech: 13
- Alchemy: 15

#### Path of Sorcery – 86

- Illusion: 13
- Conjuration: 16
- Destruction: 17
- Restoration: 13
- Alteration: 14
- Enchanting: 13

There are also [a number of other abilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36433/3389) that function more or less like perks, found by completing certain quests or objectives. These are free: you don't have spend points on them.